# How to make a date range in a single excel cell

Tags: excel

Hello all I am using Excel 2016 and trying to make a date range in a single cell. To add explanation I have a date range to submit documents for work (120-150 days out) and I am trying to have that populate in a cell to say that I have from (example) 1 June 2021 to 1 July 2021.  I know that I can do this in separate blocks by just selecting a date and saying "-120" but I was wondering if I can do it in a single cell to make it a little cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

*Update*  Answer was found by using the TEXT formula to start it. `=TEXT(A1-270, "mm/dd/yyyy") & " to " & TEXT(A1-240, "mm/dd/yyyy")`